# How to use OozieClient.doAs

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm trying to start an Oozie workflow from a web service. One of the actions should delete and create some folders. Concretely, I want to empty a folder before starting a Java action (which actually serves as a driver for MapReduce job). I know that there is a "prepare" part where in java action where you can specify the path to delete,but I need to delete all the files in a folder, but to keep the folder. That's why I'm using fs action, to delete the folder and than to make the folder.

The problem is, when I run this using oozieClient.run I get an exception that says that there is a problem with permissions, since I'm running the workflow as root user.

I found that I can use OozieClient.doAs to impersonate a specific user, but I'm not able to use it for some reason. I get internal oozie exception.

Can anyone show me how to run a workflow as a specific user, or at least point me to some good example?

Answer (score 0):

One way to run oozie job with specific user is to secure oozie using kerberos with Active Directory. So that you can authenticate for any user from active directory and run the oozie job for authenticated user.